# Selectmenu jQuery UI - How customise font-family of items in select list?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How can I set a separate font-family for each element of a drop-down list (http://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/)?
Thanks.

Comment: yes. but how add custom class for every item in select list?

Answer (score 2):

Using the `nth-child` CSS selector, have a look at the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/2p9hy3Lc/

For HTML:

```
<select name="speed" id="speed">
  <option>Slower</option>
  <option>Slow</option>
  <option selected="selected">Medium</option>
  <option>Fast</option>
  <option>Faster</option>
</select>
```

The CSS would be along the lines of this:

```
#speed-menu li:nth-child(1){
    font-family:courier;
}

#speed-menu li:nth-child(2){
    font-family:arial;
}

#speed-menu li:nth-child(3){
    font-family:georgia;
    font-style:italic;
}
```

Note that jQueryUI appends `-menu` to the id of the original element for the newly marked-up one.  Alternatively you could loop through the elements in jQuery and assign them if you are going to have a dropdown of dynamic length.